# Get specific sibling with an index-number

Tags: jquery, indexing, siblings

Im working on a banner-slideshow, but working with the navigation i've run into trouble:

```
function slideSwitch(item) {
    if(item) {

        //Problem
        var $active = $('#banner div').index(item);
        var $activeImage = $('#banner img').index(item);


    } else {
        var $active = $('#banner div.active');
        var $activeImage = $("img[src$='/images/active.png']");

        if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#banner div:last');
        if ($activeImage.length == 0) $activeImage = $('#banner img:last');
    }
}
$("#banner img").click(function () {
    slideSwitch($(this));
});
```

The problem is when clicking on an img in #banner. I want to get the position of the image (navigation.indicator) transfered and thereby be able to fade in the selected banner. The problem is here:

```
    var $active = $('#banner div').index(item);
    var $activeImage = $('#banner img').index(item);
```

Im not using index() right since I dont get an object selected.. how to do this?

I've also tried with "$('#banner div')[item]" but this still doesnt return an object..

Answer (score 3):

Using [] on a jQuery object returns the underlying HTML node for that position in the list.  What you want is to re-wrap that node in jQuery.

Try `"$($('#banner div')[item])"`

Comment: There is actually a much better way to do this... `$('#banner div').eq(item)`... Or even `$('#banner div:eq(' + item + ')`